# Getting coordinates when directions changed on drag of origin in <agm-direction>

Tags: angular, angular7

I am trying to retrieve the coordinates such as latitude and longitude when origin marker is dragged on map.

I tried to implement the dragend or dragended attributes but nothing works

html

```
<agm-map id="map" [latitude]='origin.lat' [longitude]='origin.lng' [zoom]='zoom'>
<agm-direction [origin]="origin" [destination]="destination" [renderOptions]="renderOptions" [markerOptions]="markerOptions" (dragEnded)="getcoords($event)"></agm-direction>
</agm-map>
```

ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
import { ViewChild, ElementRef, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { MapsAPILoader, AgmMap } from '@agm/core';
import {} from "googlemaps";
declare let google: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './direction.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})

export class AppDirection
{
public origin: {};
public destination: {};
public renderOptions = {
   suppressMarkers: true,
}

public markerOptions = {
   origin: {
           draggable: true,
        },
   destination: {
            opacity: 0.8,
        },
 }

 origin={lat:30.7227148,lng:76.6932551};
 destination={lat:30.7123702,lng:76.71970320000003};   

 constructor(private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader, private ngZone: NgZone){}

 ngOnInit() {}

 getcoords(event){
  console.log(event);
 }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

originDrag is the function which retrieve the latitude and longitude on origin change in `<agm-direction>` below is the code which worked for me :

html code :

`<agm-direction [origin]="origin" [destination]="destination" [renderOptions]="renderOptions" [markerOptions]="markerOptions" (originDrag)="getcoords('direction',$event)">  </agm-direction>`

in ts file :

```
getcoords(type,event)
    {
        let coords=JSON.stringify(event);
        let coords3=JSON.parse(coords);
        console.log("updated latitude :: "+coords3.lat);
        console.log("updated longitude :: "+coords3.lng);
    }
```

Hope it help others too...

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something similar to the following in your ts file:

```
    markerDragEnd($event: MouseEvent): void {
        this.markerCreator($event, '');
    }

   markerCreator($event: any): void {
     console.log($event.coords.lat)
     console.log($event.coords.lng)
   }
```

**HTML**

```
<agm-marker
  [markerDraggable]="newMarker.draggable"
  (dragEnd)="markerDragEnd($event)"
></agm-marker>
```

Comment: It does not worked i want to get the coordinates from agm-direction not from the agm marker.

Comment: can you are right. Can you create a stackbliz of your code

Comment: I have edited the code with what I am using in html and in ts file

Comment: @Poonam https://robby570.tw/Agm-Direction/directives/AgmDirection.html#destinationDrag (take a look the OUTPUTS) I tried all of them and none of them trigger my function only the "onChage"

Comment: @Poonam see I was able to get the coordinated "onChange" but not the rest, take a look to my code https://stackblitz.com/edit/agm-direction-demo-mzbaq3 I don't thing their other outputs are working